# Run a command at the start/end of each chapter without hooks

Tags: xetex, chapters, glossaries, texlive-2019

I'm using the `glossaries` package to create a list of acronyms, and I'd like to reset the first key flag for all entries at the start of each chapter in my document.

I've tried solutions I've found online, such as

```
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/after}{\glsresetall}
```

and

```
\setuphead[after=chapter][aftersection=\glsresetall]
```

However, I'm restricted to the 2019 TeX Live version with XeLaTeX and a specific cls file, so these commands are undefined.

I've also tried redefining the chapter command using

```
\let\oldchap\chapter\renewcommand*{\chapter}[1]{\oldchap{#1}\glsresetall}
```

However, this causes errors with the cls file, specifically in the abstract section. I've set up a sample [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fhzryvjdxfgs), which also contains the cls file, to demonstrate this issue.

Is there another way to call a certain command at the start/end of each chapter? An alternative solution specific to the `glossaries` package (i.e. resetting the first key flag for each chapter) would also be acceptable.

### EDIT:

This is a MWE as per the comments. It uses the `book` document class, since I can't upload the custom cls file here.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{Alpha Bravo Charlie}
\newacronym{NASA}{NASA}{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}
\newacronym{NSA}{NSA}{National Security Agency}
\newacronym{NATO}{NATO}{North Atlantic Treaty Organization}
\newacronym{EU}{EU}{European Union}
\newacronym{ECDC}{ECDC}{European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control}
\newacronym{EWRS}{EWRS}{Early Warning and Response System}
\newacronym{USA}{USA}{United States of America}


% \let\oldchap\chapter\renewcommand*{\chapter}[1]{\oldchap{#1}\glsresetall}  % Works with \documentclass{book} but causes errors with custom cls file
% \setuphead[after=chapter][aftersection=\glsresetall]  % Requires ConTeXt
% \AddToHook{cmd/chapter/after}{\glsresetall}  % Requires newer TeX Live version (and apparently wouldn't work even then?)
\xapptocmd{\chapter}{\glsresetall}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\gls{ABC}

\gls{NASA}

\gls{NSA}

\gls{NATO}

\chapter{B}

\gls{ABC}

\gls{ABC}

\gls{NSA}

\gls{EU}

\gls{ECDC}

\gls{EU}

\end{document}
```

This patching still does not seem to work, as it doesn't reset the first uses for chapter B. The same happens with `xpretocmd`.

Comment: Please always ask self-containing questions, which means: Add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) into your question. External links usually break after some time, which would make the question mostly useless. However: Maybe, e.g., package `xpatch` could be used to add code pre to command `\chapter`.

Comment: `\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/after}{\glsresetall}` wouldn't work in a current texlive either. You can only prepend commands.

Comment: I've updated the question with a MWE and a `regexpatch` attempt at a solution (I can't use `xpatch` since the two are incompatible).